# pdf printer in wine?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, pdf, printing, wine, cups

I wish to convert (print) my MS Word files to pdf on the fly ! I am on Ubuntu 9.10 and using Wine 1.1.40. Can someone help ? I have heard that pdf printer can be installed using Wine Cups !

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package you are referring to in your question is called [cups-pdf](http://www.cups-pdf.de/).  You can find it in your package manager.

Why do you need wine?  If you opena word doc in open office, you can save it as pdf directly from within [writer](http://www.openoffice.org/product/writer.html).

Comment: because sometimes some documents don't work exactly as they should in OOo, particularly vb macros.

Comment: That is the entire idea ..... my formatting changes drastically, when I make the documents in MS-Word and open it with Open Office ! ... and the installed Pdf printer is 'not found' by MS-Word installed by wine !

Answer (score 3):

just print into a postscript file via the default wine-printdialog. then convert the "printed" postscript file into pdf via

```
 % ps2pdf in.ps out.pdf
```

(`ps2pdf` should be part of the 'ghostscript' package). maybe the "[cups printing howto](http://www.witch.westfalen.de/Wine-HOWTO/ch-wine-printing.html)" helps, it covers the "printing to ps" as well.

you could also setup a [pdf-printer](http://www.cups-pdf.de/cups-pdf-CURRENT/README) in [cups](http://cups.org/), so you would print from wine to a "network printer".

Answer (score 1):

I´ve managed to run an accounting software with Wine and or Winebottle on my OSX. The trick to get the accounting software to make .pdf-s was to choose a virtual printer like cutepdf in the printer menu. This I cannot do here,
However, if there was a virtual printer I´d be happy.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the host machine from within WINE, why not install CutePDF and use that? Alternatively if you have Word 2007 Microsoft have made an add-in available that converts your documents into a PDF.

If you cannot access the host system from within WINE I would create a Samba network share in Ubuntu so that you could.